# convert this time format into seconds, SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('8: 2:9')/60);

Tags: mysql, time-format, datetime-conversion

Convert this time format into seconds:

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('8: 2:9')/60);
```

I want the output is `482` minutes in MySQL.  some times in a data base time stored with space for example '08:02:23' is saved as '08: 2:23' so want to retrieve that time to a minutes

Comment: `8: 2:9` what are these ?

Comment: time format  with space

Answer (score 0):

Right way to use it as:

```
 SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('08:02:09')/60);
```

Output : 482 minutes

`TIME_TO_SEC('08:02:09')` will be `28929 sec` & if its divided by 60, then the result will be in minutes. As you said it will be `482 minutes`.

The issue in the below query is that the space before minute.

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('8: 2:9')/60);
```

You can use it as(without space):

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC('8:2:9')/60);
```

Try this one, sometime may help:

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(REPLACE('8: 2:9',' ',''))/60);
```

Comment: I have done this method,, but I want replaced for '0' to 'space'.  09: 2:34 find the second

Comment: Why you need space in query? For display purpose you can do that, there is no issues.

Comment: with in the quotes that is to be consider as a time with help of colon , first value is hour,after colon is minutes,then last is seconds use some function to find it

Comment: :-) I know about time format. I'm asking you for what reason you are placing space in it for a SQL. If you need result, you HAVE TO remove that space. Please try to remove the space in front of minute before you inserting time in QUERY.

Comment: some times in a data base time stored with space for example '08:02:23' is saved as '08: 2:23' that's why i am asking

Comment: Edited my answer, So by using `REPLACE()`, if there is unwanted space in data it may be replace a correct format is placed for second calculation

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELIMITER $$

 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `tim_to_min`$$

 CREATE FUNCTION tim_to_min(f_time VARCHAR(30))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
   DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

 DECLARE h VARCHAR(30);
 DECLARE m VARCHAR(30);
 DECLARE s VARCHAR(30);

 SET h=SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_time,':',1);

SET m = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_time,':',2),
 LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_time,':',1))+1),':','');

 SET s = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_time,':',3),
 LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_time,':',2))+1),':','');


 RETURN ROUND((h*60)+m+(s/60),0);
  END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

--> use this stored function in mysql

then call the function..

```
SELECT tim_To_min('8: 2:9'); /*call function tim_to_min */
```